# TypeError: processing xml format wikipedia to text format

Tags: python, text, mining

I am learning Python, mainly for text mining, following guidance of (http://textminingonline.com/training-word2vec-model-on-english-wikipedia-by-gensim). I want to extract wikipedia English text from xml returned by api. However, an error appears:

```
print(globals()['__doc__'] %locals())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'dict'".
```

Could anyone please give any tips on how to sort this problem out? Do I need to replace the `outp` and `inp` by the address of the files?

Thanks in advance. I have attached the code:

```
import os
import logging
import sys

from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

if __name__=='__main__':

    program = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    logger = logging.getLogger(program)

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    logging.root.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)


    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print(globals()['__doc__'] %locals())
        sys.exit(1)

    inp, outp = sys.argv[1:3]
    space = ' '
    i = 0

    output = open(outp, 'w')
    wiki = WikiCorpus(inp, lemmatize=False, dictionary={})
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(space.join(text) + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            logger.info('Saved ' + str(i) + ' articles')

    output.close()
    logger.info('Finished ' + str(i) + ' articles')
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in your print statement? print the locals inside some string? what should be in the `__doc__` variable that doesn't exist?

Comment: Many thanks for the kdin reply. I am a new user of Python and have no programming background. I just copied the codes from the mentioned website. It works when I degrade to Python 2x and execute the .py and wiki.bz2 in the cmd environment (Execute “python process_wiki.py enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 wiki.en.text").

Comment: hmm, that print statement is weird, but it looks like it's just to complain if you don't provide the necessary arguments. Try changing it to something like: `print("We need both source and destination files. Exiting...")` just so it passes. BUT if you are getting the error, seems like you are not providing the right arguments. Try manually typing the command (make sure items are separated by a space).